Printing contents of several files after listing them with ls
Although it seems to be a simple task, I am struggling to print the contents of several files that have been filtered in this way:
$ ls *_pattern_*
a_pattern_a
b_pattern_b
c_pattern_c
total_pattern_total

ls *_pattern_* | grep -v total
a_pattern_a
b_pattern_b
c_pattern_c

ls *_pattern_* | grep -v total | xargs cat
cat: 'a_pattern_a': No such file or directory
cat: 'b_pattern_b': No such file or directory
cat: 'c_pattern_c': No such file or directory

Perhaps I need to buy some more coffee... Any hints are much appreciated.

I suspect there are spaces in the filenames, use ls -b *_pattern_* to see it escaped.

Parsing the output of ls is generally a bad idea to begin with.. You should be able to do this with extended globbing.

Also, no repro: https://ideone.com/6EhBVq

I vote for SO to allow emojis, this would deserve a laughing one without meaning something different than "yes, get more coffee" and on a worldwide perspective, it allows you to guess where the one resides you're talking to (here it is early evening on a saturday - not many people thinking about more coffee, but more about other beverages.... ) ;-D

find *_pattern_* -prune -type f ! -name '*total*' -exec cat {} +


-prune avoids descending to subdirectories if any of  *_pattern_* is a directory
-type f handles no matches at all or match being a directory


The single-quotes in the sample error messages indicate that ls escaped some characters in the filename. Consider:
$ touch a! a\ b a_c
$ ls a*
'a b'  'a!'   a_c


... Which is why you should never use ls in scripts.
